# Problem 5 of chapter 6 of Evans PDE 1st.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I don't know how to start it. I try to compute the $Lv$ , but nothing I get.Maybe, I think some hint is suitable for me . Thanks.

> [image]
>   [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $Lv\leq 0$ for $\lambda$ large enough, the maximum principle implies that
$\|v\|_{L^\infty(U)} \leq \|v\|_{L^\infty(\partial U)}$. Therefore,
$$
\big\||Du|^2\big\|_{L^\infty(U)}
\leq \|v\|_{L^\infty(U)}
\leq \big\||Du|^2+\lambda u^2\big\|_{L^\infty(U)}
\leq \big\||Du|^2+\lambda u^2\big\|_{L^\infty(\partial U)}
\leq \big| \| |Du|^2 \big\|_{L^\infty(\partial U)}
+ \lambda \big\| |u|^2 \big\|_{L^\infty(\partial U)}
\leq C^2(\|Du\|_{L^\infty(\partial U)}+\|u\|_{L^\infty(\partial U)})^2.
$$